# What exactly happens in the Bellman-Ford Algorithm if there is a negative weigth cycle?

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand exactly why the Bellman-Ford Algorithm would not work with a negative weight cycle. I do understand that negative weight cycles will prevent the program from giving the right answer. But what exactly happens in the program if there is negative weight cycle?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm guessing this should be on programmers.stackexchange

Comment: Bellman-Ford in fact *does* work correctly in the presence of negative cycles! If there is a negative cycle reachable from the source, you  can find it.

Comment: You can find negative cycles, but these indeed prevent the algo from finding the shortest path.

Answer (score 1):

The Bellman-Ford algorithm finds the *shortest path* from a source vertex to all other vertices in a weighted graph.

The issue with negative-weight cycles is that ***there is no shortest-path***.

Without drawing, consider the case of 4 nodes, where A is the source, and nodes B,C,D are other vertices.

Weights of all the edges are as follows:

```
w(A,B) = 1
w(B,C) = 1
w(C,D) = 1
```

Bellman-Ford would conclude the following shortest path lengths

```
path(A~B) = 1
path(A~C) = 2
path(A~D) = 3
```

But what if we added an edge that created a negative weight cycle.  For example an edge from C to B with a weight of -2.

```
w(C,B) = -2
```

Now there is a negative weight cycle.  By walking `(B,C,B)` we get a total path weight of -1 (1 + -2).

If we were to run Bellman-Ford again, it would give us what it thinks is a shortest-path from A to D just as it did previously.[Note 1]

But this time, it would be wrong.

In fact, it wouldn't matter what integer shortest path weight the algorithm gave us because we could ***always*** find one that was shorter.

For example, say the algorithm gave us the original path weight of 3 `(A,B,C,D)`.  Well, it's easy to see that we could construct a *shorter* path: `(A,B,C,B,C,D)` which gives us a path weight of 2.

But that's not the shortest path either.  For example `(A,B,C,B,C,B,C,D)` gives us a path weight of 1.

As you can see, we can construct an ***arbitrarily short*** path weight by repeatedly looping between vertices B and C.  This is only true because our graph contains a negative weight cycle.

So it's not that Bellman-Ford doesn't correctly find the shortest path.
... More accurately, ***there is no shortest path***.

[1] It's not difficult to detect negative weight cycles in Bellman-Ford, so this assumes a naive implementation.